# orbeon calculated fields in a repeat break after first itiration

Tags: xpath, repeat, orbeon

In my Orbeon form, I am using a repeat with calculated fields within the repeat.  For example, my repeat includes two integer fields, 1) total number of crayons and 2) number of clue crayons.  The third field is a calculated field showing the the percentage of blue crayons.  using the following Xpath expression,

```
if ($LMI-Bene ne 0) 
then $LMI-Bene div $Total-Bene * 100 else 0
```

I am able to calculate the percentage.  The problem comes when I add a new iteration to my repeat and even the first line stops working.  I think this could be because the control names of each iteration are the same, but I'm not sure how to account for that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relative XPath to the value rather than the binding variable.

In example try

```
if (../LMI-Bene ne 0)
then ../LMI-Bene div ../Total-Bene * 100 else 0
```