# Obtain values of a radio button inside a repeat in a XForm

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am having some problems with repeats in XForms. I need to access to some values of a radio button field that is inside a loop. The scope is to make visible an input text if the radio button has selected an specific value. I want this behaviour for all repetitions (radio button and input text field is inside the loop).

It works fine for one row, but when I add a new row, the code does not work any more.

I copy a simple example to check this behaviour:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:odt="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/datatypes"
     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
     xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xpl="java:org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.api.FunctionLibrary"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Loop</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>DHszw</application-name>
                <form-name>Loop</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Loop</title>
                <description xml:lang="en">Description of the form.</description>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <category-1>
                    <subcategory-1-1/>
                    <element-1-1-1/>
                    <loop-group-0>
                        <loop-0>
                            <element-1-1-2/>
                            <element-1-1-3/>
                        </loop-0>
                    </loop-group-0>
                    <element-1-1-4/>
                    <element-1-1-5/>
                </category-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:bind xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel" id="fr-form-binds"
                 ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="category-1-bind" name="category-1" ref="category-1">
                <xf:bind id="subcategory-1-1-bind" name="subcategory-1-1" ref="subcategory-1-1"/>
                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-1-bind" name="element-1-1-1" ref="element-1-1-1"/>
                <xf:bind id="group-loop-0-bind" name="group-loop-0-bind" ref="loop-group-0"
                         relevant="($element-1-1-1='yes' )">
                    <xf:bind id="loop-0-bind" name="loop-0" ref="loop-0" relevant="($element-1-1-1='yes' )">
                        <xf:bind id="element-1-1-2-bind" name="element-1-1-2" ref="element-1-1-2"
                                 relevant="($element-1-1-1='yes' )"/>
                        <xf:bind id="element-1-1-3-bind" name="element-1-1-3" ref="element-1-1-3"
                                 relevant="($element-1-1-2='yes' )"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>
                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-4-bind" name="element-1-1-4" ref="element-1-1-4"
                         relevant="($element-1-1-1='no' ) or ($element-1-1-2='no' )"/>
                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-5-bind" name="element-1-1-5" ref="element-1-1-5"
                         relevant="($element-1-1-1='no' ) or ($element-1-1-2='no' )"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css filename="" mediatype="text/css" size=""/>
                <pdf filename="" mediatype="application/pdf" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <category-1>
                        <label>LoopCategory</label>
                    </category-1>
                    <subcategory-1-1>
                        <label>&lt;b&gt;BasicSubcategory&lt;/b&gt;&lt;hr&gt;</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </subcategory-1-1>
                    <element-1-1-1>
                        <label>Do you want a loop?</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                        <item>
                            <label>yes</label>
                            <value>yes</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>no</label>
                            <value>no</value>
                        </item>
                    </element-1-1-1>
                    <element-1-1-2>
                        <label>Do you want an Input Text?</label>
                        <hint>More</hint>
                        <alert/>
                        <item>
                            <label>yes</label>
                            <value>yes</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>no</label>
                            <value>no</value>
                        </item>
                    </element-1-1-2>
                    <element-1-1-3>
                        <label>Your input text</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-3>
                    <element-1-1-4>
                        <label>Why no loop?</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-4>
                    <element-1-1-5>
                        <label>End:</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-5>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="loop-0-template">
            <loop-0>
                <element-1-1-2/>
                <element-1-1-3/>
            </loop-0>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel">
            <fr:section bind="category-1-bind" id="category-1-control">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/category-1/label"/>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <xf:output bind="subcategory-1-1-bind" id="subcategory-1-1-control">
                            <xf:label mediatype="text/html" ref="$form-resources/subcategory-1-1/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/subcategory-1-1/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        </xf:output>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <xf:select1 appearance="full" bind="element-1-1-1-bind" id="element-1-1-1-control">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-1/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-1/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-1/item">
                                <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                <xf:value ref="value"/>
                            </xf:itemset>
                        </xf:select1>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
                <xf:group bind="group-loop-0-bind" id="group-loop-0-control">
                    <fr:grid bind="loop-0-bind" id="loop-0-control" max="10" min="1"
                             origin="instance('loop-0-template')"
                             repeat="true">
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:select1 appearance="full" bind="element-1-1-2-bind" id="element-1-1-2-control">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                    <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/item">
                                        <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                        <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                    </xf:itemset>
                                </xf:select1>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:input bind="element-1-1-3-bind" id="element-1-1-3-control">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-3/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-3/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                    </fr:grid>
                </xf:group>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <xf:input bind="element-1-1-4-bind" id="element-1-1-4-control">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-4/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-4/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        </xf:input>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <xf:input bind="element-1-1-5-bind" id="element-1-1-5-control">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-5/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-5/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        </xf:input>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

If this code is run in a Orbeon server, it works fine until we add a new row in the 'repeat' element. Then the input field  disappear (or is not visible) regardless the value selected in the radio button.

I imagine, that adding the copy of the row, probably will have the same element name (or changes the original element name) and causes this issue. But I need to access to the value of the radio button for each row. Is it possible? Is it a known bug? How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the relative path to the element instead of the bind variable to refer to element values within the repeat, so in your case:

Replace:

```
($element-1-1-2='yes' )
```

with

```
(../element-1-1-2='yes')
```

See also [orbeon calculated fields in a repeat break after first itiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720929/orbeon-calculated-fields-in-a-repeat-break-after-first-itiration)

This won't work outside the repeat; I'm not sure of your intended logic in the second element-1-1-2 condition.

Regards

jez

Comment: Exactly; for now Jez workaround is the way to go. But @JorgeHortelano, what you were doing was correct, and it just doesn't work inside repeats right now because of this bug https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/776. (Luckily the workaround isn't too complicated.)

Comment: Hi Alex. I'm intrigued you call it a 'bug', I see it more as a constraint on using binding variables. For instance, if the variable was used outside the repeat (repeat context not available) wouldn't it become undefined?

Comment: when used outside of the repeat, what the variable should point to is arguable. But when used inside the repeat, the expectation really is that it would point to the node in the "current iteration". There is very similar to the problem of dispatching events to controls inside repeats. In that case too, which control(s) that get the event depends on where the event is dispatched from, and that case is properly implemented, so the algorithm is already mostly there.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It is working correctly! I have not found this solution on the web.